# Additional queue and blob containers are getting created while running Azure Durable Function in local development environment

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-durable-functions, azure-queues

I have created a Azure Durable function with targetframework:.NET Core 3.1, which gets triggered whenever an entry is added to the Azure Queue which in turn invokes the Orchestrator function. This Orchestrator function triggers other activity functions which are part of a workflow process. While running this application in my local development environment with all the settings managed in local.settings.json, I noticed some additional Queues and Blob containers are getting created in the Azure portal.

Azure Queue:

1. [AzureFunctionAppName]-control-00
2. [AzureFunctionAppName]-control-01
3. [AzureFunctionAppName]-control-02
4. [AzureFunctionAppName]-control-03
5. testhubname-control-00
6. testhubname-control-01
7. testhubname-control-02
8. testhubname-control-03

Azure Blob Containers:

1. azure-webjobs-hosts
2. zure-webjobs-secrets
3. [AzureFunctionAppName]-applease
4. [AzureFunctionAppName]-leases
5. testhubname-applease
6. testhubname-leases

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

There is no issues, this is by design:

> Azure Storage is the default storage provider for Durable Functions. It uses queues, tables, and blobs to persist orchestration and entity state. It also uses blobs and blob leases to manage partitions. In many cases, the storage account used to store Durable Functions runtime state is the same as the default storage account used by Azure Functions (AzureWebJobsStorage).

You can however specify a seperate storage account to be used by the framework if you want:

> However, it's also possible to configure Durable Functions with a separate storage account. The Azure Storage provider is built-into the Durable Functions extension and doesn't have any other dependencies.

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-storage-providers#azure-storage))

There is also the option to use a [different storage provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-storage-providers).